# Как добавить кнопку на html? [JS]

Tags: javascript

Появилась надобность немного апгрейтить хедхантер. Необходимо добавить на страницу кнопку при нажатии на которую будет происходить некое действие.Кучу информации перерыл, но так и не нашел нужной. Все используется как плагин для хрома

Вот сюда должна добавляться кнопка
[image]

```
if(document.location.href.includes("https://hh.ru/resume/"))
{
    //если страница именно резюме, то необходимо добавить кнопку
}
```

Как это сделать? С JS не дружу

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для запуска скрипта на целевой странице правильнее указывать это в разделе манифеста

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "https://hh.ru/resume/" ],
        "js": [ "app.js" ]
    }
]
```

А для вставки можно написать так:

```
document.querySelector('.parent-element')
   .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button onclick="someAction()">Run Action</button>');
```

`.parent-element`- селектор элемента, в конец которого нужно добавить кнопку

`someAction()` - функция, которая запускает некое действие

Comment: Спасибо! Все варианты перепробовал, кроме этого:)

Сначала долго мучался ибо не запускалось , а потом в селекторе вместо одинарных кавычек поставил двойные и все заработало